# Como personalizar a chave de retorno do meu validator no laravel?

Tags: laravel

Atualmente o meu validator retorna como chave o campo que não passou na validação, gostaria de saber se tem como trocar para um nome genérico, como "erros" para que eu possa percorrer no frontend.

Segue o validator:

```
protected function create(Request $data)
    {

        $messages =[
            'nome.required'=> 'Precisamos saber o seu nome, preencha por favor',
            'email.required'=> 'Precisamos saber o seu nome, preencha por favor',
            'senha.required'=> 'Você precisa preencher uma senha para efetuar o cadastro.',
            'email.unique'=> 'Opa, esse email ja foi cadastrado, coloque outro.'
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($data->all(), [
           'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
           'nome' => 'required|string|max:50',
           'senha' => 'required'
       ], $messages);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);
        }

        return User::create([
            'nome' => $data['nome'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'telefone' => $data['telefone'],
            'usuario_anjo' => $data['usuario_anjo'],
            'senha' => Hash::make($data['senha']),
        ]);        
    }
}
```

No caso eu recebo:

```
{"email":["Opa, esse email ja foi cadastrado, coloque outro."]}
```

Como posso trocar para "erro" ?

Comment: E o que te impede de percorrer no front-end com a chave atual?

Comment: Dá pra dizer por qual motivo vc deseja alterar isso?